# In Magento how can I make zip/postal code as optional?

Tags: magento

I am using Magneto 1.7, I want to make zip/postal code   not require (optional) in customer form. When I add new customer address or edit customer address .I need to remove zip/postal as optional. I do Google lots of and found some solution like below and remove the client side validation form these file but this solution is not working for me.

```
      I am also giving the screen shot of the customer form where I need to make the zip code not require
```

![enter image description here][1]

```
Please suggest me how can I make zip/postal code as optional
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We have in built feature in Magento to Specify Countries for Optional Postal Code. Using this feature you can select countries from which you want to remove validation.

You can access this option after logged in admin panel. From Top Navigation System >> Configuration >> General. In Countries Options Group you can find the dropdown with named " Postal Code is Optional for the following countries ".

Hope this help!!

Comment: Thanks  But is there any way to remove require (*) from code because I need to make optional  as default all country  without selecting any country

Comment: You can do this by CSS or by modify particular template in your theme.